# What is the difference between mole and molar mass?

Tags: physical-chemistry, everyday-chemistry, mole

In my book it says 1 mole of carbon =1gram atom of  carbon =12 gram if I see this relation that seems to me that 1 mole is mass of an atom In grams.
But molar mass is different and why we use for example grams/mol.
Why is molar mass is not in grams as my book says.
Differences between mole and molar mass and why do we use g/mol instead of gram for molar mass because unit of mass is kg or gram.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Your own reasoning – based on searching, reading, learning and thinking – is supposed to be present to avoid the question closure for lack of own explicit  effort.  [How do I ask a good question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).  Asking should be rather the last than the first idea coming to your mind.

Comment: If you did little searching and reading, you would not need to ask:   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mole_%28unit%29   and  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molar_mass

Comment: If the unit of M had been kg, units in the equation m=n.M would not have matched ( kg = mol . kg )

Answer (score 1):

Mole merely is a counting (like pair, dozen, hundred) of objects, although a rather large one: $\approx 6.022 \times 10^{23}$.  It is used to count electrons (think electrochemistry), atoms, molecules.

Gram atom is an outdated unit, superseded by molar mass $M$ which is the mass of of $\pu{1 mol}$ e.g., of atoms (or, more frequently, molecules).  Because it reports the ratio of mass *per* number of items, $M$ is expressed in $[\pu{kg/mol}]$.  While $\pu{1 mol}$ of $\ce{H}$ (atoms) equates to $\pu{1.008 g}$, $\pu{1 mol}$ of $\ce{H2}$  (dihydrogen molecules) is about $\pu{2.0 g}$.  (Note, there is Avogadro's number $N_a \approx \pu{6.022 \times 10^{23} mol^{-1}}$, then used with a unit.) In the lab, $M$ is frequently expressed in $[\pu{g/mol}]$, too.

The rest is [dimensional analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_analysis).  If you define the mass of an individual molecule with $m_a$:

$$ M = N_a \times m_a \leftrightarrow [\pu{g mol^{-1}}] = [\pu{mol^{-1}}] \times [\pu{g}]$$

Thus, if you have $\pu{3.5 mol}$ of $\ce{H2}$ *molecules*, with known  molar mass $M$:

$$ m = \pu{3.5 mol} \times \pu{2.0 g mol^{-1}} = \pu{7.0 g}$$

"Mass" is not the same as "molar mass".

Comment: sorry for carbon mistake edited my question. If unit of mass is kg or gram why do we use kg/mol or gram/mol for molar mass why this mol.

Comment: Note the difference between the unitless Avogadro number and the Avogadro constant.

Comment: @poutnik Can you explain it in detail I did not grasp that.

Comment: @Remy As stated, molar mass refers to the mass for $\pu{1 mol}$ units counted (not a single, not a dozen) *as reference*.  Similar to driving a car, it isn't about you used $\pu{2 L}$ of petrol to drive to your friend, but how far you may drive with one liter *per* $\pu{100 km}$.

Comment: @Remy Being a comment to answer, without explicit recipient, it was targeted to the answer author. //A.number is just a number. A constant has dimension 1/mol.

Comment: You said "Mass" is not the same as "molar mass. Here is an anology as one gram atom of carbon is different than one gram of carbon atom. That's how mass is different 
from molar mass. All misconception is due to terms used to describe them as I referred in my anology above. Am I right? Or there is something else.

Comment: Not yet.  In "gram atom of carbon", "gram atom" is one concept, and "of carbon" the gerund (as in "a bottle of water", "a crate of apples") which would be about 12 g or about 1 mol in contemporary terms. The differs from "one gram of carbon atoms", about only $\pu{1 g}/\pu{12 g mol^{-1}} = \pu{83 mmol}$.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you will better understand with a numerical example. Read carefully the following sentences. Each one is a little bit more complicated than the previous one.

Start with : $1$ mole $\ce{C}$ contains $6·10^{23}$ atoms $\ce{C}$ and weighs $12$ g.

$2$ moles $\ce{C}$ contains $2·6·10^{23}$ atoms $\ce{C}$ and weighs $2$ mol · $12$ g/mol  = $2· 12 $g = $24$ g.

$3$ moles $\ce{C}$ contains $3·6·10^{23}$ atoms $\ce{C}$ and weighs $3$ mol · $12$ g/mol = $3·12$ g = $36$ g

$10$ moles $\ce{C}$ contains $10·6·10^{23}$ atoms $\ce{C}$ and weighs $10$ mol·$12$ gmol = $10$·$12$ g = $120$ g

$0.02$ mole $\ce{C}$ contains $0.02·6·10^{23}$ atoms $\ce{C}$ and weighs $0.02·12$ g = $0.24$ g

$n$ moles $\ce{C}$ contains $6·n·10^{23}$ atoms $\ce{C}$ and weighs $n·12$ g,

$1$ mole $\ce{Oxygen atoms}$ contains $6·10^{23}$ atoms $\ce{O}$ and weighs $16$ g, or better : $16$ g/mol

$n$ moles $\ce{O atoms}$ contains $6·n·10^{23}$ atoms $\ce{O}$ and weighs $n·16$ g.

As a consequence, the mass of $1$ mole $\ce{C-12}$ is by definition the molar mass of $\ce{C-12}$ and the molar mass is $12$ g/mol

The mass of $1$ mole Oxygen atom is the molar mass of O, and it weighs $16$ g/mol. The molar mass is the mass of $1$ mol of this atom.

If you know the molar mass of an element, you can calculate the mass of any sample of this element, provided you know the number of moles of this element in this sample.

Example : The molar mass of the iron atom is $56$ g/mol. As a consequence a sample containing $0.2$ mole iron weighs $0.2·56$ g = $11.2$ g.

If the molar mass is called $M$ (in gram/mol), and the mass of a given sample of a pure element is called $m$ (in gram), the weight of $n$ moles af a given element is :  $m = n·M$. Check the units !

Furthermore you can obtain the number of moles $n$ in this sample by using the formula : $n = m/M$. Example, taken from the previous paragraph.

How many moles of iron are there in $11.2$ g iron ? Answer : $n = m/M = \frac{11.2 g}{56~ g/mol} = 0.2~ mol$

Comment: But why still g/mol why not gram because it states that it is molar MASS. Sorry I could not understand

Comment: @Remy It does not only say it is molar MASS, it also says it is MOLAR mass, i.e the mass of 1 mol. Similarly, density is sometimes called specific mass, with unit kg/m^3, not kg because of being mass.

Comment: @Remy For easier understanding, imagine that the term  "molar mass" in g/mol is renamed, not containing the word mass at all, similarly as specific mass [ g/cm3 or kg/m3] is usually called just density. By other words, consider "molar mass" as a single term, not as mass with adjective.

Comment: @Remy I have added an example of application at the end of my message to show you why the molar mass is in gram/mol, and not in gram. Check the units of the formula $n = m/M$

Comment: Now it seems I am getting some of this.

Comment: @Remy Solution molar concentration $$c \ \pu{mol/L}=\frac{m\ \pu{g}}{M\  \pu{g/mol}\cdot V\ \pu{L}}$$ where $m,M,V$ are solute mass, solute molar mass and solution volume.

Comment: @Maurice I think my problem is mathematical more than chemical. Please tell me which is right and why which is wrong and why from the two. #1( mass of one atom of carbon 12 = 12 amu/carbon atom) #2 ( mass of one atom of carbon 12 = 12 amu carbon atom)

Comment: @Remy Neither. The mass of 1 atom 
12C
 is 12 amu. As atom, in contrary to mole, is not a physical unit. From mathematical point view there is important that physical quantity has 2 components. numerical value and it's unit. Putting them in equation, both numerical and unit equations must match. See also that "mass of 1 mol of 12C" is 12 g, but "molar mass of 12C" is 12 g/mol. Like mass of 1 L of water is approx. 1 kg, but it's specific mass is 1 kg/L. Similarly, specific energy has the unit J/kg, not J.

Comment: @Poutnik Thanks a lot you are trying to make me understand. (Here is an anology as one gram atom is an element having a weight in grams numerically equal to the element's atomic weight. And one gram of an atom is different that is "converting atomic weight from amu to gram). And we take" gram atom"as single term and a different concept and do not take "gram" in the term as adjective. That's how molar mass is single term and different concept and we should not take it as mass with adjective. Am I right?

Comment: @Remy I highly recommend you reading wikipedia articles for any term of interest before asking. // I would fully abandon the very obsolete quantity name "gram atom". It is not used in western chemistry for decades, even if it may be still taught in India. //  1 gram atom = 1 mol of the respective atoms. 1 gram of atoms, the same as 1 gram of anything is still 1 g. And yes, mass conbined with certained adjectives forms terms, qualitatively different to mass. // Note mole=unit name like kilogram, mol=unit symbol like kg.

Comment: No, you are right. Anytime when you are in doubts about units, take an equations with quantities of interest and plug there the supposed units instead of numbers. Evaluate the equation and if there is not match, something is wrong. For more, see [Dimensional analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_analysis) // As homework, derive units for conductance, conductivity and molar conductivity

Comment: Accidentally deleted my comment which was before @Poutnik,s above comment writing it again for better understanding .[@Poutnik I am justing drawing an anology that how we should not be confused of terms due to words that are used in them like in obsolete "gram atom" we should not confuse our self with gram. Because it is 1gram atom =1mole not the gram of 1atom of some element. That's how mass and molar mass are different. Or am I again wrong?]

Comment: @Remy. You are right. The term "gram atom" has been replaced by the word "molar mass" in order to avoid confusions similar to yours. A "gram atom" is not the mass in gram of an atom. It is the mas of 1 mole of an element.